# Rails Setup: mysql2 gem always causing problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm fairly new when it comes to commandline or Rails, but work on a rails project where I'm doing the frontend.

I've installed all gems that are needed for the project, but lately some errors occur when doing a `rake:db migrate` or today when trying to deploy the current version via `cap production deploy`

The problem I'm facing seems to have todo with the `mysql2` gem. At least that is what the console says.

When running `cap production deploy` I get this error:

```
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile.
```

and further down this …

```
Gem::LoadError: can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

What do I have todo here? When I do `gem list` I see that **mysql2** is installed.

Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Rails used to have the `mysql2` gem locked down to `~>0.3` in the codebase.

So that is what it looks for but your Gemfile will simply state

```
gem "mysql2"
```

Pretty sure they've updated this in the latest release of rails 4 so either:

Update to the latest version of rails 4 or use a specific version of the mysql2 gem

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.20"
```

Comment: I just installed rails 4.2.2 but when doing ```rails -v``` it still says rails 4.0.1 … http://i.imgur.com/cAsG31S.png

Comment: You'd need to update the rails version in the `Gemfile` and run bundle install.  Also `4.2.5` is the latest version